# I'm having trouble building a solution on Windows 10 using Mono

Tags: msbuild, mono, csproj, solution, csc

I have been having trouble building my solution on Windows 10 using Mono.

I started out trying to build the whole solution for the game I'm working on. This solution builds just fine on Mac (using Mono) but we can't get it working in Windows 10.

As I have gone down the rabbit hole on this problem I have narrowed everything down to the point of building a nearly-empty Solution file that references a single `.CSProj` file, which itself is empty, and I'm still getting errors.

Here are the steps that have lead me to where I am now.

1. Fresh install of Windows 10
2. Install Mono 5.16
3. Install .Net Framework developer pack for .Net 4.7.1
4. Copy my solution to the machine
5. Open Command Prompt
6. Navigate to the solution directory
7. Run `C:\Program Files\Mono\bin\msbuild.bat`

I get the following error:

```
C:\ProgramFiles\Mono\lib\mono\msbuild\15.0\bin\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.target(52,5): 
error MSB6006: "csc.exe"exited with code 1. 
[C:\Users\bconley\workspace\test\TestProj\TestProj.csproj]
```

In the output of `msbuild.bat` it tells me what command it was executing when things failed, so I try running that on its own:

```
"C:\Program Files\Mono\lib\mono\msbuild\15.0\bin\Roslyn\csc.exe" /noconfig /nowarn:1701,1702 /nostdlib+ /platform:AnyCPU /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /define:DEBUG;TRACE /highentropyva+ /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7.1\mscorlib.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7.1\System.Core.dll" /debug+ /debug:full /filealign:512 /optimize- /out:\Debug\TestProj.dll /subsystemversion:6.00 /target:library /utf8output Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs "C:\Users\bconley\AppData\Local\Temp\.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1.AssemblyAttributes.cs"
```

That command gives the following error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Text.Encoding.CodePages, Version=4.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I'm completely stumped. It seems like I'm missing some fundamental dependency. I assume Mono still works on Windows?

Comment: what kind of project are you building? does it require a NuGet restore? (e.g. .net core applications)

Comment: No, there should be no need for NuGet. In the course of troubleshooting this issue I have reduced it down to a single, empty csproj and a solution file that points to it and I'm still having problems.

Answer (score 3):

Finally found a solution. They just don't ship System.Text.Encoding.CodePages.dll with csc.exe.
Drop it from NuGet or Visual Studio

```
Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\bin\Roslyn\
```

into

```
Mono\lib\mono\msbuild\15.0\bin\Roslyn\
```

Comment: Thanks for the info! I had completely forgotten about this issue (posted 11 months ago). I wound up working around this by installing the non-mono VS build tools. Good to know that there is a non-hacky fix!

I upvoted your answer, but apparently I'm too new to Stack Overflow for it to count.

Thanks again!